# DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet is this the OAth key?

Tags: model-view-controller, dotnetopenauth, access-token

I have spent the past 6 hours smashing head against internet until I found a solution to getting and storing an OAth key which could be used to post to a twitter wall without a user giving permission. I have finally got DotNetOpenAuth working and I have a successful Authorisation from

```
VerifyAuthentication(this.HttpContext);
```

and I have found a dictionary (ExtraData) which contains a key "accesstoken" but I have no idea where to go from here... is this accesstoken even what I need... Sorry for rather vague question but twitters api has got my head going in circles (facebooks was MUCH easier)

TLDR

To Actually end on a question. Is this accesstoken somthing I can store and use at later dates?

And once I have this access token (which doesn't expire for long periods) how can I use it to post from that tokens account onto another twitter wall?